# CSS Override table align="right"

Tags: html, css

Is there a way using css to override a table's align="right" attribute?

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
```

It makes the table behave as if it were floating right and I need to stop this with a media query at a certain width.

Code example for those asking:
https://jsfiddle.net/swLyfuwm/

Note: The table is not made by me and I can't change it, as much as I'd like to just remove it completely.

Comment: show some code to know what problem you have.

Comment: Have you tried to add text-align inside the CSS in the table tag. Maybe that could help.

Comment: have you tried table {text-align: left !important; }

Comment: The align "attribute", not property, was deprecated years ago and you should not be using it.

Comment: It would be easy to answer your question if you could post with HTML/CSS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
```

Should be:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align:right;">
```

Also, you shouldn't be using any of those other attributes. All of this should be replaced by CSS properties. I would recommend you read a tutorial on CSS.

Edit to reflect the updated question:

If you can't change the table, then:

```
table { float:left; }
```

That will move the table to the left. The text will remain unchanged.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I  can't change the table. I am looking for a css override if there is one.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. The align attribute is equivalent to the following CSS: style="float:right; text-align:right;". So depending on what you want to do, you can set one or both of those to left.

Comment: float:none does what I want. I thought I had tried it earlier with no result. I must've assumed it wouldn't because it didn't have a float... you know what they say about assumptions! thanks for your input.

Comment: It's an understandable assumption. For example, if it were align=center, then float:none wouldn't work in that case. Or if you were trying to replicate align=center with CSS then you would use margin:0 auto instead of float. Also, going back to the original question, the table can be fixed using float:initial (sets it back to default).